# T SQL: Row_Number() Not working

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have syntax like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PId, VDate ORDER BY VDate) As RowNum
```

When I look at the result set, I am seeing many instances of 2 rows with the same PId and the same VDate - both having RowNum 1 when I am expecting a 1 and a 2.

I have tried changing my `ORDER BY VDate` to `ORDER BY OtherDateColumn` ... no difference.

Questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my syntax?
2. Is there a requirement that the Dates in my Order By have to be different for each row with the same PId and VDate?
3. Are there some other basic requirements the data itself must meet?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add group by PId, VDate

Comment: Where would I put the Group By?

Comment: Can you show the error dataset and query? Based on your query for Same PId and VDate you will get different row numbers in sequence starting from 1. If either PId or VDate changes then you will get different sequence starting from 1

Comment: You have vdate in Partition By and Order By.  Perhaps ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By PId Order By VDate) As RowNum

Comment: Hi @John! What I am trying to do is if a PId has multiple records with the same VDate - then I want the count to increment till the VDate changes. Then, I only want to pull out the rows with a RowNum of 1

Comment: The 'problem' I am seeing with my data is that in cases where I want the RowNum to increment, all values in the row are identical [which is typical for this particular set of data that I am working with]. Does the data in the field I am doing the Order By have to be distinct for each row?

Comment: ... all values in the rows ...

Comment: Hi! I solved my problem by putting all my data [without the Row_Number()] in a Table Variable and then doing the Row_Number() ... in a Select statement on that Table. It works fine. Thanks so much for your suggestions! I sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: That  would not be a correct solution. Did you have `row_number()` in a subquery that is then joined to another table?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you have a JOIN in your query, you may have 1 to many relationship, which gives the result with duplicate values.

Secondly you are partitioning on two values, Pid and the Vdate. This combination is the unique value on which the row_number gets its value. Partitioning only on Pid and sort by Vdate could also help.